# Regular Expression to Exclude Wild Character

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a javascript file that validates string and substitude a character for another. One of the requirements is to exclude numbers [0-9] and special characters \W. But the asterix known as "wild char" * must be included. So I have the following regex that works for everything except the wild character. it is excluding it and I need to make an exception when I run into it.. how can I modify my regex for this scenario?

```
/!?([0-9])|\W/.test(code[j])
```

Comment: Please provide more sample strings.

Comment: Use `/!?[0-9]|[^\w*]/.test(code[j])`. I wonder if you really wanted `!?[0-9]` though, it matches an optional exclamation mark followed with a digit.

Comment: Asterisk ? When you say `So I have the following regex that works for everything except the wild character` what exactly do you mean by **_works_** ?

Comment: Did it work for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the option to use multiple matchers when testing strings in RegEx. Your performance may vary, but I would suggest looking into something like this:

```
!?([0-9]|\*)|\W.\test(code[j])
```

Of course, you didn't really provide any sample strings, so I had to infer your usage. Using the escape character `\` you're able to treat `*` as a regular character and you can add it to your matcher. Additionally you could also shorten it to

```
!?(\d|\*)|\W.\test(code[j])
```

Where `\d` would match any digit -- its' the same as [0-9] just shorthand.

Check it out https://regex101.com/r/E3uied/2

Comment: What language is this?

Comment: Javascript -- you can see in the regex 101 link

Comment: The question is about JavaScript and includes `/.../.test(code[j])`.

`!?(\d|\*)|\W.\test(code[j])` is not valid JavaScript.
Is there a typo or is your answer in a different language?

I ask because that has something that looks like a regular expression but without the beginning `/`.  Instead of a closing `/` before `.test` it has a backwards slash in the middle of `.test`.

Comment: Oh whoops, good call. I didn't ever look to see that, I just included it in the regex assuming the author had a purpose for it since there were no sample strings. You're totally correct, complete oversight on my part